# Any example of using join in query applyable for npoco

Tags: npoco

Could you give me any example of querying and mapping result set from joined tables? I have following code:

DTO:

```
public class FormCatalogRecord
{
    [Column("MFormId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("SGroupId")]
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }

    [Column("SGroupName")]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [Column("STypeFormId")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Column("MFormKod")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Column("MFormName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("SFormPeriodName")]
    public string Period { get; set; }

    [Column("MFormDateStart")]
    public DateTime? DateStarts { get; set; }

    [Column("MFormDateEnd")]
    public DateTime? DateEnds { get; set; }

    [Column("MFormPublish")]
    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
string formsQueryStr =
                    "FROM MForm " +
                    "INNER JOIN SFormPeriod ON MForm.SFormPeriodId = SFormPeriod.SFormPeriodId " +
                    "INNER JOIN SGroup ON MForm.SGroupId = SGroup.SGroupId " +
                    "ORDER BY MForm.SGroupId";

var test = db.Fetch<FormCatalogRecord>(formsQueryStr);
```

The result is exception: "Ambiguous column name 'SGroupId'".
I tried to change attribute:

```
[Column("MForm.SGroupId")]
public int? GroupId { get; set; }
```

Now I get an exception

> Invalid column name 'MForm.SGroupId'

Surprisingly I didn't found any examples in official documentation. Any help valid for npoco will be useful.

**UPDATE**

For my first case I'm getting following SQL generated:

```
SELECT 
    [MFormId] AS [Id], [SGroupId] AS [GroupId],
    [SGroupName] AS [GroupName], [STypeFormId] AS [TypeId], 
    [MFormKod] AS [Code], [MFormName] AS [Name], 
    [SFormPeriodName] AS [Period], [MFormDateStart] AS [DateStarts], 
    [MFormDateEnd] AS [DateEnds], [MFormPublish] AS [PublishDate] 
FROM 
    MForm 
INNER JOIN 
    SFormPeriod ON MForm.SFormPeriodId = SFormPeriod.SFormPeriodId 
INNER JOIN 
    SGroup ON MForm.SGroupId = SGroup.SGroupId 
ORDER BY 
    MForm.SGroupId
```

I think I need some way to add "MForm." before "[SGroupId] AS [GroupId]". Would be nice if column attribute could support syntax like [Column("TableName.ColumnName")]

Answer (score 0):

NPooc and PetaPoco are different projects now it's hard to relate each with the other these days.

As for your question. Have you tried

```
string formsQueryStr = 
                    "SELECT MForm.*" +
                    "FROM MForm " +
                    "INNER JOIN SFormPeriod ON MForm.SFormPeriodId = SFormPeriod.SFormPeriodId " +
                    "INNER JOIN SGroup ON MForm.SGroupId = SGroup.SGroupId " +
                    "ORDER BY MForm.SGroupId";

var test = db.Fetch<FormCatalogRecord>(formsQueryStr);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. All objects have default property values. NPoco simply can't map column names to properties, as it uses SQL AS statement to rename column when mapping. Although I can write appropriate SELECT by hand, it will be too complex and unmantainable.

Comment: Just curiuos: you aswered on question for npoco, while contributing to petapoco. Can petapoco handle this? I think about feature request (or maybe pull request). See updated question. I know my tables have 
unusual column names, but I can't change this and need treat this some way.

Comment: Well, it seems petapoco can do correct mapping with SELECT *. But using * means overhead, isn't it? I don't need all this columns...

Comment: I didn't think PetaPoco would have this bug because of how table columns are added to the sql statement -`string.Join(", ", (from c in pd.QueryColumns select tableName + "." + provider.EscapeSqlIdentifier(c)).ToArray())`. Here is an [integration test to confirm](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/commit/2135805ed2c4f8ce3f6a1a7f5611fe9b9a56a5bd)

Comment: I meant overhead, not overlap. It seems petapoco doesn't have any options to autogenerate select clause for queries with join. So I need either use * to select all including unnecessary columns or write redundant sql by hand.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand. Does your POCO include properties from both tables?